# Can one build Wilson lines in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gauge-theory, wilson-loop

This question has two parts:

1. Firstly, I am curious if one can build Wilson lines as a 'parallel transport operator' in general relativity in direct analogy with what is done in gauge theory. For a given space time, can we build an operator $W(x^\mu,y^\mu)$ which takes tensors in the (co)tangent bundle at the point with coordinates $y^\mu$, to the tensors in the (co)tangent bundle at the point with coordinates $x^\mu$ (assuming the Levi-Civita connection)? [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/498002/) makes me believe it to be possible. If it can be built, do we not do so simply out of fashion, it being standard in GR to solve the geodesic equation along some path?
2. Secondly, if we are in a general curved space-time, how, if at all, does the usual Wilson line construction in gauge theory change due to the additional holonomy of the underlying spacetime?

Comment: Regarding 1) absolutely: General relativity is essentially a gauge theory with the principal bundle being the orthonormal frame bundle $OLM$, a fibre-wise construction using the pseudo-Riemannian metric. The Christoffel symbols are then the gauge field and the story is much the same. The tensors live in the associated bundles and the parallel transport construction lifts there as well. See chapter 23 here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nchF1fRGSY3R3rP1QmjUg7fe28tAS428/view